# Setting a value to a field in XPO

Tags: c#, xaf

If I want to assign a default value to a BO's field while saving it (in my Controller class), How can I achieve this using C# and xaf? Which events are relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding this code to my overriden save methods:

```
    private void ProcessSelectedObject(System.Collections.IList list)
    {
        foreach (object obj in list)
        {
            if (obj is Contact)
            {
                if (((Contact)obj).Sector == null)
                {
                    ((Contact)(obj)).Sector = "Default";
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OnSaving Method

```
public class MyObject:XPObject
{
    protected override void OnSaving()
    {
       if(this.Session.IsNewObject(this))
             //SetDefaultValues
       base.OnSaving();
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks indeed. As a newbie I can't construct the proper logic. How can I get the proper business object for example Contact class? Do I need to use IObjectSpace ?

Comment: Your Contact class inherits from which class?

Comment: I use this BusinessObject from another module so that I don't have direct access to its class. That's why I'll handle this in a controller class

Comment: It inherits from XPBaseObject class

Comment: If you don't have access to that class my solution does not work for you,please show us the code in your controller